# fadeout effect doesn't work well when called inside for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, fadeout, effect

My code is really simple but I've been having this problem for a long time.  I really need to know the correct way of doing this.

I have lots of `div`s in a list.  Each one has its own `id`. There is a button to remove the selected `div`s, something like this:

```
function int_groups_removeGroups(id) {
   $("#"+id).css("background-color","#FFABAB");
   $("#"+id).css("background-color","#FFABAB").fadeOut('slow');                                             
}                               

 groupsize = groupsArray.length;        
 for (i =0; i <= groupsize; i++) {
    int_groups_removeGroups("group_"+groupsArray[i]);
 }
```

Everything works except the effect of `fadeout`.
What is happenning is when I click on the button to remove, the `div`s simple blink in red and then disappear.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What browser is producing the problem?

Comment: I'd recommend setting up a http://jsfiddle.net/ for people to help you better

Comment: Incidentally, you could optimize your code by adding a class to all those DIVs and selecting that, instead of selecting each individual ID.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing way to much. These two lines should suffice:

```
var groupids = '#group_' + groupsArray.join(', #group_');

$(groupids).css("background-color","#FFABAB").fadeOut('slow');
```

The first line composes a string of your ids, the second passes it to jQuery, which fades out each one.

If you are still experiencing performance issues, then you are animating too many divs in parallel.

Comment: I solved the mystery :S The problem in this case was after the loop finishes I call a function the changes the HTML of the container that holds all divs mentioned... Thanks anyways :D